# How to initialize vector inside constructor from private in c++ similarly to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, c++, class, arraylist, vector

I'll try to make this as simple as possible

In Java, I would do the following:

```
public class foo{

    private final int x;  
    private final ArrayList<classname1> one;
    private final ArrayList<classname2> two;

    //constructor
    public foo(int x){
        this.x = x;
        one = new ArrayList<>();
        two = new ArrayList<>();
        menu();
    }
```

I would then use 'one' and 'two' throughout my code

I'm currently however using c++ and I was reading that the equivalent of ArrayList in C++ are vectors. I've tried experimenting however I'm finding it difficult to understand how I would initialize the vectors inside the constructor like the java code.

This is what I have so far in c++:

```
class foo{

private: int x;
private: vector<classname1> one;
private: vector<classname2> two;

public: 

//constructor
foo(int x) {
 this->x= x;
 //how would I initialize the vectors here like in java? Something like but of course it doesn't work:
        one = new Vector<>();
        two = new Vector<>();
 menu();
}
```

Thank you! Any help appreciated.

Comment: It depends what you want to initialize it to, which you should clarify. But not doing anything is fine, if you want default initialized vectors.

Comment: Just `foo(int val) : x(val) { menu(); }`. `one` and `two` are in the same allocation space than the `foo` object. If you want to make them independent from the `foo` class, you should declare it with `unique_ptr<vector<classname1>> one` or with another smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to initialize. `std::vector` has its own default constructor. Unless you need to explicitly initialize a `std::vector` with some initial content, nothing needs to be done.

The reason you have to do what you have to do in Java is because in Java all objects are not really objects. They are actually pointers to objects. Therefore, Java constructors must meticulously initialize each one using the `new` keyword. This is not true in C++.

C++ objects work fundamentally differently. You will do yourself a big favor if you completely forget everything you know about objects, while you are learning C++. It's going to be hard, because C++'s syntax, in this area, is very similar to Java's, but C++ objects work fundamentally differently than they do in Java, and if you keep trying to draw analogies you will only get confused, and go down the wrong path time and time again.

The correct way to learn and understand C++ objects, is by reading a good C++ book, and not thinking about Java.

Same thing goes for everything else. The "private" keyword in C++ is not the same as the "private" keyword in Java. Of the three instances of "private" in your C++ code, only the first one is needed. The other two accomplish absolutely nothing.

C++ is not Java.